# MySQL Join statement to get data from two tables into a datagridview

Tags: mysql, sql, join, visual-studio-2015, datagridview

I have two tables that I'm trying to join, 'holidays' and 'users'.

Users contains all my user info, the the column 'id' being primary and unique.
Holidays contains a column called 'userid', which corresponds to the id in the user table.

I'm struggling to get the join statement to work... what I'm looking for is the result of the select statement to give me the friendlyname (column 'fname' in user table) instead of giving me the value of userid.

Here's what I'm trying...

```
 SELECT * FROM holidays JOIN users on users.id=holidays.userid WHERE holidays.status = 0
```

But i'm not getting a correct result - SQL executes without error, but my DGV is filled with tons of erroneous results.

Apologies If I have not used the correct terminology or whatever.
I'm new to the concept of joins.

Here is hopefully a better explanation of what I am after...

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: Fair comment - info added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the specific values you want from every table in the JOIN:

```
SELECT u.fname
FROM holidays h
JOIN users u
ON u.id = h.userid
WHERE h.status = 0
```

by the alias (`FROM users u`) you can select column from users table by `u.fname`

Answer (score 0):

First try to right join to the `User` table. If you just want the `fname` then select the `column name` in the SELECT query, as `SELECT *` takes more time then `SELECT column name`.

Comment: Please take a few minutes and review the "How do I write a good answer" in Stack Overflow help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer